# The below code is working fine on Pycharm but its getting runtime error in Hacker Rank. Can you tell me the reason?

Tags: python

***Code-***

```
n = int(input())
scores = []

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    scores.append(x)

scores.sort()
print(scores[-2])
```

**In hacker rank its showing**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'
```

**But in Pycharm and Anaconda it compiling and giving the right output completely fine.**

Comment: Hackerrank is evidently giving input as a sequence of numbers in one line separated by space. If you do that yourself you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it appears that the input is passed as a single line string in Hackerrank so this code will not work as here it assumes you pass the numbers in new line:

```
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    scores.append(x)
```

You can use `split()` if the input is in single line.

Using list comprehension:

```
scores = [int(elt) for elt in input().split()]
```

Using `map()`:

```
scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
```